# custom fonts in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I created a presentation in PowerPoint 2010 using some new free fonts that I downloaded.

Though both the .pptx and .ppsx files look perfectly formatted on my laptop, everyone that I sent it to for review got messed up versions of both- different fonts, sizes, overlapping etc.

What should I do? The slides look great on my laptop! I understand it's because these fonts are not available in the other person's PowerPoint, but shouldn't the .ppsx version at least look the same for other people?

Is there any way to keep the fonts and make sure they see it how it actually is?

Comment: Unless you can get this prospective employer to download the font files on their PC (yeah right), you're going to want to just go with a clean, readable, **built-in** font. Don't over complicate something they probably wouldn't even notice.

Comment: Convert it to .pdf if you don't have animations.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [embed the fonts](http://blogs.office.com/b/office_blog/archive/2010/07/01/how-powerpoint-font-embedding-and-replacement-can-save-your-presentation.aspx) you're using.  I agree that this is somewhat risky and you should at least test this before sending the file to the prospective employer.

Answer (score 0):

If your potential future employer needs to edit it, the problem becomes very complicated, as you'd need to send the fonts to him (embed them or attach them) and have the fonts be automatically downloaded to his machine before he opens the powerpoint file.

However, if you just want him to be able to view the powerpoint, I'd suggest saving it as a `.pdf` and sending it that way.  The fonts should be perfectly viewable to anyone to whom you pass this along in a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

A PPSX is essentially just a PPTX with a different extension; the extension determines how Windows launches the file when you doubleclick it and in the case of PPSX, your computer's file associations tell Windows to tell PPT to open the file in slide show view.  The file itself is nothing special and won't contain any fonts that the PPTX doesn't.

Some fonts are embeddable, some are not.  If the font is fully embeddable and you choose to embed it when you save, it'll be installed on computer of anyone else who opens the file, so it'll be editable.  Or if the font's partially embeddable, it'll be temporarily installed but only for viewing.  It all depends on the font and the characteristics its author has given it.

Keep in mind that the presentation file will grow by roughly the size of the embedded font file; this can sometimes make for large PPT/PPTX/PPSX/etc files.